# self in Python classes

Tags: python, class, self

I know first argument in Python methods will be an instance of this class. So we need use "self" as first argument in methods. But should we also specify attribures (variables) in method starting with "self."?

My method work even if i don't specify self in his attributes:

```
class Test:
  def y(self, x):
    c = x + 3
    print(c)

t = Test()
t.y(2)
5
```

and

```
class Test:
  def y(self, x):
    self.c = x + 3
    print(self.c)

t = Test()
t.y(2)
5
```

For what i would need specify an attribute in methods like "self.a" instead of just "a"?

In which cases first example will not work but second will? Want to see situation which shows really differences between two of them, because now they behave the same from my point of view.

Comment: Attributes and variables are different things. Use `self.` if you want an attribute of `self`. If you want a variable, don't use an attribute.

Comment: Where is a difference between attribute and variable? attribute of class = variable assigned in this class. How `c` assigned in the examples. Not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you do self.attribute_name in a class method is to perform computation on that instances attribute as opposed to using a random variable.For Example

```
class Car:
  def __init__(self,size):
      self.size = size

  def can_accomodate(self,number_of_people):
      return self.size> number_of_people

  def change_size(self,new_size):
      self.size=new_size

   #works but bad practice      

   def can_accomodate_v2(self,size,number_of_people):
       return size> number_of_people

 c = Car(5)
 print(c.can_accomodate(2))
 print(c.can_accomodate_v2(4,2))
```

In the above example  you can see that the can_accomodate use's self.size  while can_accomodate_v2 passes the size variable which is bad practice.Both will work but the v2 is a bad practice and should not be used.You can pass argument into a class method not related to the instance/class for example "number_of_people" in can_accomodate funtion.
Hope this helps.

Comment: You said "not related", but "can_accomodate " seems related to our class/instance...

Comment: Why it's a bad practice while bot variants are works? I agreed that it's a bad practice but want to see on the practice where "can_accomodate_v2" not works or works as not expected, while "can_accomodate" still works fine. Why it's bad practice and should not be used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "not related" I meant the "number_of_people" argument/variable passed to can_accomodate function, as the number_of_people is not relevant to the Car class per say. Regarding the Bad practice part, consider you initialize 2 objects of Car class c1 and c2 with size of 4 and 10 receptively.So now if you call c1.can_accomodate(2) it will return true as it should,However if you call c1.can_accomodate_v2(10,9) it will return true again which is incorrect as c1 has size of 4 and it cannot fit 9 people, You could call  c1.can_accomodate_v2(self.size,9) to get the correct result.

Comment: However a class method it would cause redundancy and confusion for someone using Car class in his implementation.